# What is this technique called: a(b(x)) -> f(a, b)(x)?

Tags: naming-conventions

I am trying to give a proper name for function `f`:

```
a(b(c(x))) == f(c, b, a)(x)
```

what is this technique called?

Comment: I guess you are mapping functions over the variable?

Comment: function `f()` here takes an array of functions as argument, and returns a new composite function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found my answer, it is function composition:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition

So I will give a name `compose` to my function.